# How to checkout a Ruby gem project for local development?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fluentd

For example, consider the `fluentd` project: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/master/bin/fluentd

After I have perform a `git clone`, I can run the server inside the `bin` folder, e.g.

```
./bin/fluentd
```

And in this file, I can see it will load the `lib` folder in the root folder

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path(File.join(here, '..', 'lib'))
```

As there are dependencies such as `cool.io` I need to installed before I can successfully run this project, how to download and installed all the needed dependencies in the `lib` folder?

Answer (score 1):

That project uses Bundler, so simply ensure it’s installed (`gem install bundler`) and then run:

```
bundle install
```

in the project root directory.